# Convert VBA code to T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, encryption, converters

I have an encryption project where I need to convert this VBA code into T-SQL. I am a SQL developer and I am having a hard time trying to figure out what this VBA code is trying to do:

```
Public Function XORDecryption(DataIn As String) As String

Dim lonDataPtr As Long
Dim strDataOut As String
Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
Dim CodeKey As String

CodeKey = "R@ndomWord7"

For lonDataPtr = 1 To (Len(DataIn) / 2)
'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
intXOrValue1 = Val("&H" & (Mid$(DataIn, (2 * lonDataPtr) - 1, 2)))
'The second value comes from the code key
intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))

strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
Next lonDataPtr
XORDecryption = strDataOut
End Function
```

Plus this code needs to be converted as well:

```
Public Function XOREncryption(DataIn As String) As String

Dim lonDataPtr As Long
Dim strDataOut As String
Dim temp As Integer
Dim tempstring As String
Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
Dim CodeKey As String

CodeKey = "R@ndomWord7"
For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn)
'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid$(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
'The second value comes from the code key
intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))

temp = (intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
tempstring = Hex(temp)
If Len(tempstring) = 1 Then tempstring = "0" & tempstring

strDataOut = strDataOut + tempstring
Next lonDataPtr
XOREncryption = strDataOut
End Function

'USAGE
    Private Sub cmdEncryptdecrypt_Click()
    Dim strEncryptedText As String
    'strCodeKey = InputBox("Please enter your password", "XOr Encryption")
    strEncryptedText = XOREncryption("TestEncryptedWords")
    ' Note:  the strEncryptedText should be:  140B1C1B28390C001D4726250A33001F331C
    MsgBox XORDecryption(strEncryptedText)

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: So here is the approach.  (1) Figure out what the code is supposed to do.  (2) Determine the appropriate data structures needed in SQL.  (3) Re-implement the code.

Comment: Code like that should be deleted rather than converted. Seriously -- one of the weakest possible encryption schemes (which can literally be broken using 19th century cryptanalysis since it is in effect just a Vigenere cipher -- broken in the 1850s) with a fixed key as well.

Comment: @John  I love your comment.  I was just thinking it didn't look to hard to crack...

Comment: SQL Server already has very strong encryption capabilities. Throw away this code and use one of the available options

Comment: To expand on my comment. I don't know the politics of OP's situation -- but if this is something that OP has been tasked to do at work and it is meant to be in production code then it could show a certain amount of initiative to suggest to the powers that be that it would be better to use a more secure encryption method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you explain to me how to use these "encryption capabilities"? I'm a Junio SQL developer so I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Assumably, the original author is gone, so...   if you have anyone in the shop who knows ANY version of VB ( .Net, VBS, VBA, VB Classic ), get their help in reverse engineering the VBA code.

Once you understand the WHAT and HOW of the VBA Code, you'll be able to match the functionality in TSQL.

Otherwise...it's trial by fire.    Do web searches on the VB commands and learn them one by one.  Fortunately, there are not very many in that block of logic.

Comment: Your code sample above can be pasted directly into a VB6 project and it runs without modification.  It can be pasted into a VB 2010 .Net project and the only change is to set a default value = "" to the STRDATAOUT variables.  So, you can very easily step execute it and figure out what it is doing.    Essentially, it loops thru the input string, taking 1 byte from the string, converting into ASCII, then taking 1 byte from the CodeWord, and convert that to ASCII, strings them together does an XOR operation, converts that to HEX, adds a "0" if the hex result is only 1 byte long, adds that to ....

Comment: adds that to STRDATAOUT...repeat until at end of string, return to caller.  The input string is at that point converted/encrypted.  The merely basically reverses that.   So, in TSQL you will need to be able to 1) iterate a string, one byte at a time, calculate an offset using a modulus operation, convert to ASC, convert to HEX, perform and XOR, and concatentate a string.    TSQL is not as strong at these things as VB, C# and other languages, but it can be done.

Comment: I'm assuming the encrypted results are stored in a database.    ( perhaps as encrypted passwords ? )    If so, I second the recommendation of  Panagiotis Kanavos, and strongly suggest you use the existing VBA Decryption function to decrypt the existing database values, and re-encrypt them using SQL Server encryption features.  And....adapt the application to use SQL Server to do the encryption  & decryption work going forward.

Comment: Here is a link explaining XOR in ciphering.  Hope this helps..      
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Answer (score 0):

Ridan,   I've commented the original code with additional comments to help clarify what is happening.   My comments are in the form of '##   comment.....

Hope this helps.

```
Public Function XORDecryption(DataIn As String) As String

Dim lonDataPtr As Long
Dim strDataOut As String
Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
Dim CodeKey As String

CodeKey = "R@ndomWord7"
'   establish a loop, to walk thru theinput string, stepping thru it two ( 2 ), yes two bytes at a time.
For lonDataPtr = 1 To (Len(DataIn) / 2)
'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
'###     Take the 1st of two bytes from data in.  Let the Val function know that this data exists in its Hex form
'###     Place it into intXOrValue1
intXOrValue1 = Val("&H" & (Mid$(DataIn, (2 * lonDataPtr) - 1, 2)))
'The second value comes from the code key
'###    Take the 2nd of two bytes from data in.  
'###     Place it into intXOrValue2
intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))

'###     Do an XOR on the two fields ( intXORValue1 and intXORValue2) and then convert the results to its CHR form
'###     Place the result into strDataOut ( via concatenation )
strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
'###    Loop until done....
Next lonDataPtr
'###    Return result to caller
XORDecryption = strDataOut
End Function

Plus this code needs to be converted as well:

Public Function XOREncryption(DataIn As String) As String

Dim lonDataPtr As Long
Dim strDataOut As String
Dim temp As Integer
Dim tempstring As String
Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
Dim CodeKey As String

CodeKey = "R@ndomWord7"
For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn)
'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
'###   Pull one byte of data from the input string.  On first pass thru loop pull byte # 1, on 2nd pass pull byte # 2, etc
'###   Convert that one byte to its ASCII form 
'###    Place it into variable intXORValue1
intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid$(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
'The second value comes from the code key
'###   Pull one byte of data from the Codeword.  Chose that one byte based on the result of this formula :
'###      divide lonDataPtr by the length of CodeKey ( 11 bytes in this case ) and hold onto the REMAINDER following the division
'###      add 1 to the remainder ( in case it was 0 )
'###      Now, pick the Nth byte from Codekey  ( as calcuated above with the division and modulus and the plus 1 )
'###         and...convert it to its ASCII form
'###        and place the result into intXORValue2
intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))

'###   Now, do the XOR operation, placing the result into the variable TEMP
'###      see this web page for more on the XOR operation :
temp = (intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
'###   Convert the TEMP result into its HEX form
tempstring = Hex(temp)
'###   If it is only 1 byte long, prefix it with a "0".  
'###     as you will see in the Decrypt function, two bytes of output for each 1 byte of input is important.
If Len(tempstring) = 1 Then tempstring = "0" & tempstring
'###   Add it ( via concatenation) to the output string
strDataOut = strDataOut + tempstring
Next lonDataPtr
'###   When all bytes converted....return the encrypted result to the caller.
XOREncryption = strDataOut
End Function

'USAGE
    Private Sub cmdEncryptdecrypt_Click()
    Dim strEncryptedText As String
    'strCodeKey = InputBox("Please enter your password", "XOr Encryption")
    strEncryptedText = XOREncryption("TestEncryptedWords")
    ' Note:  the strEncryptedText should be:  140B1C1B28390C001D4726250A33001F331C
    MsgBox XORDecryption(strEncryptedText)

End Sub
```